# creating a procedure which takes list as an argument

Tags: scheme, racket

I am a newbie in scheme and I am trying to write a procedure which always finds a list's tail's first element. This is important in recursive calls.

Here is my procedure :

```
(define second (lambda (x) (car(cdr(x))))
```

and this is how i try to check it whether it runs correctly or not:

```
>(define x (list 1 2 3 4))
>(second x)
```

and this is the error :

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: (1 2 3 4) (no arguments)

 === context ===
stdin::184: second
/usr/share/racket/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:85:7
```

What might be the problem? Can you give me an inspiration? Is my definition of "second" wrong or what?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running this in DrRacket?  If so, you should see a red highlight over the region where the error occurs.  Do you see this?

Comment: no i was trying it on terminal

Comment: If you can, try running with DrRacket; the extra support it provides  should be useful when you're learning the language.

Comment: I actually use DrRacket but I was trying only this code piece on terminal. In fact I couldnt get used to DrRacket:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an extra, unnecessary pair of parenthesis in your code. This fixes it:

```
(define second (lambda (x) (car (cdr x))))
```

To be clear, this was wrong: `(cdr(x))`. The correct form is: `(cdr x)`. Remember, whenever you need to apply a function `f` to an argument `x` the correct way is: `(f x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme uses S-expressions, so instead of `car(x)`, you should use `(car x)`. In your case, that means  `(car (cdr x))`, not `car(cdr(x))`.